# How to extract data from an email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have emails coming through with the following data:

> Your EagleView Measurement is ready for the following order:
> •
> •   Report ID: 26048369 (Premium, $60.00, 4740 sq ft)
> •   Address: 123 Apple St, City, FL 32456-####

I need to take the address "123 Apple St" and put it into a variable to be called later.

I get

> run time error 13 mismatched type.

when running this code:

```vb
Sub Extract()

'Define Variables
Dim sFileName As String
Dim Address As Variant

Set myfolder = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

For i = 1 To myfolder.Items.Count
    Set myitem = myfolder.Items(i)
    msgtext = myitem.Body

    'Search for specific Text
    delimitedMessage = Replace(msgtext, "Address: ", "###")
    delimitedMessage = Replace(delimitedMessage, ",", "###")
    Address = Split(delimitedMessage, "###")

    'Alert box showing if the code worked
    MsgBox "The Address is: " + Address
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

'Address' is an array of strings, so it's throwing an error when you try to display it. You want the fourth element of the array, which is zero-indexed. Just replace `MsgBox "The Address is: " + Address` with `MsgBox "The Address is: " + Address(3)`

Comment: Ok, that explains why it throws the error; however, as I go through the array starting with 0 and working my way up, it seems as though it's taking the data from the header of the email.

The data I'm looking to extract is in the body of the email.

I tried changing the variable name to myextractedstuff, but that just throws the same error

Comment: What do you mean the header of the email? Do you mean the subject? Or is there more text in the email that you're not showing here?

Comment: This is what it seems to be including in the array:

From: customerservice@vendorcompany.com <customerservice@vendorcompany.com> 
Sent: Thursday, December 6, 2018 8:09 PM
To: admin@mycompany.com
Cc: careers@mycompany.com
Subject: EagleView Report 26048369 - 123 Apple St, Mexico Beach, FL (Premium, $60.00, 4740 sq ft)

Then comes the body of the email

0 in the array returns:
From: customerservice@vendorcompany.com <customerservice@vendorcompany.com> 
Sent: Thursday

The solution you gave does work, but I just had to figure out where in the array what I was looking for is.